# Is it possible to stop notifications of an OTA update?

Tags: ota-update

I rooted and modded my Samsung Prevail (Gingerbread) a couple weeks ago, and all is going well there.

However, I am now getting notices about an OTA system update, which I have no intention of installing. I will wait for the makers of my mod to produce a parallel version.

In the meantime, is there any way to kill the constant notices about the update?

Comment: tagged as clockwork mod since that was part of the rooting/modding process I followed.

Comment: removed the clockwork mod tag as it has nothing to do with the issue :) Check for `fota-kill`, that's what e.g. CyanogenMod uses to stop the OTA stuff (see e.g. [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1068513) and [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-ii-epic-4g-touch/198283-how-do-i-stop-getting-ota-update-notifcation.html)).

Answer (score 3):

On my S2 running ICS, there are options available for notification as well as downloading via Wi-Fi. Look under SETTINGS > ABOUT PHONE > SOFTWARE UPDATE

If you don't have such options and you have a rooted phone, use software like Titanium Backup to FREEZE the software update module.

Comment: I'm on GB, and there were no comparable options I could find. The FREEZE method via Titanium Backup seems like a viable option, and earned my +1, but I wasn't so sure I was finding the correct thing to freeze. I'll have to poke at that some more. Incidentally, though; it seems that after you cancel it enough times, it goes dormant for a while, then comes back a few times, and goes dormant again. I expect it'll keep coming back, though, so I'm going to look more closely at the options via TB.

Answer (score 0):

On my device (it runs Jelly Bean) there is an option under SETTINGS > APPLICATION > All ('Tab')

Now select the "software update" app and then click on "turn off/disable".

This will stop the over the air notification for system update and whenever you want to update then "turn on/enable" the app again.