# How to stop notifications of OTA update after rooting?

Tags: root-access, ota-update

I recently rooted my device (4.1 version Asus tablet). However, when I connect my device to internet, it automatically search for  and download system firmware update every time. Then it asks me to tap the notification to update the system. There is no option provided to disable that. How can I disable checking as well as downloading the update?

I read [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/is-it-possible-to-stop-notifications-of-an-ota-update) question also, but there is no solution.

Edit: My device is Asus MeMo Pad tablet.

Comment: What is the tablet model? Please mention it.

Comment: @k1chy I edited the description. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having root, use Titanium Backup to disable/freeze CMClient.apk & DMClient.apk. This will disable the tablet to check for OTA from Asus servers.

If you want to update the tablet to latest firmware later, unfreeze/enable the apks and proceed with updating.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Could you upvote my question please?