# Remove Galexy edge s7 system update notification

Tags: samsung, ota-update, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I want to remove system update notification and never update it's system.
it's force stop is inactive. what can I do?

Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all options require root.

1. The most clean and safe option is to edit `build.prop` file. Use any file manager which provides access to root filesystem.
   You can learn about build.prop [here](http://pocketnow.com/2015/01/15/build-prop-tweaks).

   The setting which is of interest to us is `ro.build.version.release`.

> ro.build.id=JSS15J 
> ro.build.display.id=JSS15J.I9505XXUEML1
>   ro.build.version.incremental=I9505XXUEML1 
> ro.build.version.sdk=18
>   ro.build.version.codename=REL 
> **ro.build.version.release=4.3**
>   ro.build.date=Tue Dec 10 14:28:08 KST 2013
>   ro.build.date.utc=1386653288 
> ro.build.type=user ro.build.user=se.infra
>   ro.build.host=R0210-09 
> ro.build.tags=release-keys
>   ro.product.model=GT-I9505 
> ro.product.brand=samsung
>   ro.product.name=jfltexx 
> ro.product.device=jflte
>   ro.product.board=MSM8960 
> ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
>   ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi 
> ro.product.manufacturer=samsung

Just change it to 7.0 and Android will be fooled and think that you **already** on Nougat. For 100% fooling you can also change `ro.build.id`, `ro.build.display.id` and `ro.build.version.incremental` properties to `NRD90M`, `NRD90M.G955FXXU1AQDG` and `G955FXXU1AQDG` values correspondingly (aka Nougat values).

Reboot after the applying changes.

2. If you lack root, you still *can try* [Titanium Backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56153/94888). But this way can also require root though.