# Disable system update notification?

Tags: rooting, root-access, ota-update

Simply put, I get this notification at times

[image]

I want to stop that.

Please no stuff about "you should do the update". I'd have to unroot, do the update, reroot, restore all my data. It's just not worth it for minor updates.

Comment: You should at least clarify the phone model. From the screenshot it looks like a Moto - there should be plenty posts about disabling OTA altogether on Moto phones floating around the web.

Comment: Use `build.prop` file. See my detailed answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/174171/94888).