# How to get rid of OTA software update notification?

Tags: notifications, ota-update

I upgraded my Nexus 4 to Lollipop a few days ago but I don't like it. I'll leave out my reasons because they're not relevant here. I wiped my phone and installed a clean stock 4.2.2 version instead. I'm happy with this.

Not long after, Android automatically downloaded the 4.3 upgrade and notifies me with the choices "Later" and "Install". I don't want to do this upgrade.

**How do I:**

- get rid of the notification, and
- remove the downloaded update (to free up precious storage space).

---

I have already tried choosing "Later" but the same notification immediately reappears.

Based on Google search results, I also tried going to `Settings > Apps > All > Google Services Framework` and unticked "show notifications" but it still appears. Force stop or disable also doesn't seem to help, so I've re-enabled the service including notifications. I didn't see any other apps in this list that sounded relevant - did I just not see it?

Comment: Related: our [ota-update tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ota-update/info) / [Is it possible to stop notifications of an OTA update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24210/16575) Guess you chose the wrong place to "disable notifications" – it should be *Settings › Apps › All › Software Update* according to the linked post. Does that work?

Comment: Thank you @Izzy - unfortunately there's no app named "Software Update". I have the list sorted alphabetically and there's nothing between "Skitch" and "Sound Recorder".

Comment: Might be named "slightly different" (manufacturers, you know – and you didn't name your device). I'd check *all apps* to see if there's something that might match. Have you? Maybe it's "OTA Updater", or just "Updater".

Comment: You're right - I forgot to mention that it's a Nexus 4! (How could I have...?) I can't investigate right now but will respond later. I believe I did scroll carefully through the entire list already but I must have missed it if there's really an app with a self-explanatory name.

Comment: Never hurts to check twice :) Please also [edit] your question to include the device name, as it might "get lost" in the comments. Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can disable these notifications by unchecking the notifications for Google Play Services [Not Framework]. This fixed my problem on the LG G3 and I assume it will on all other devices.

The best option is to click and hold the notification and then select 'App info', which will take you to desired app info for that update notification. Then uncheck the notification option there.

Comment: `Go to Settings > Application Manager > All > Google Services Framework and then uncheck "Show notifications".` [source](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/54639/16606)

Comment: For Lollipop, it is "Apps" instead of "Application Manager"

Comment: After un-check notification in "Google play service". The notification was still in panel. I did long touch it, then from menu select "app info" and force stop. Will see if it appear again...

Comment: Since my question was marked as a dupe.  This does not work on a Galaxy S5 nor on a nVidia Shield K1.  Both Google Services Framework AND Google Play Services have had notifications unchecked.  The popup upgrade still persists.  Log pressing on the notification takes me to System Updates app and the "Show Notifications" is checked but can not be unchecked.  I have force stopped but it, of course, comes back.