# Can not disable Software Update application

Tags: applications, updates, ota-update, application-autoupdate, application-manager

I have an older Android phone and recently updated to Android v5. Since the update I keep receiving a notification on my screen to update the software again (it also automatically downloads a 250mb file). This update however has no effect (it keeps re-installing the same version). I am therefore looking for a way to disable it.

A [previous post on this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88159/251355) suggested to go to the Application Manager > All > Software Updater and then subsequently to Disable the app and clear the cache.

I did this but it had no effect. In fact it made things more complex:

- I have now two Software Updater apps (one is v3.19 which I cannot disable, and the other is v4.2 which I turned off)
- After disabling v3.19, I cannot do anything anymore when opening it. It is not turned off and all buttons are disabled (see screenshot below).

[image: Two Software Updater Apps][image: Screenshot of v3.19]

Comment: Is it rooted? If yes then things are easy.

Comment: What is rooted?

Comment: Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android) . If you haven't done any of the following, then your phone is not 'rooted' :D

Comment: @papakias We have a question [What is root? What do I gain from rooting?](/q/1).

Comment: And without rooting?

Comment: Without rooting, you have limited control over your phone, and may have trouble trying to disable some apps, like the one you're facing.

Comment: Thats quite a lot of effort just to disable a notification

Comment: @JohnAndrews That's because the average user is supposed to stay up to date, I guess.